# Doing rotation for AVL

Tags: c++, computer-science, avl-tree

I am trying to implement an AVL tree for educational purposes but the rotation is not working like I expected.

I have nodes which each have a pointer to a left, right and parent node.

Below is my code for the right-right rotation. First the imput (Just so I make it clear, this is what I understand to be the RR case)

```
a
  \
   b
    \
     c
```

Code to do rotation is

```
if (subTreeRoot == root) {
  this->root=subTreeRoot->right;
}
else { // not resetting at root
  subTreeRoot->right->myParent = subTreeRoot->myParent;      
  subTreeRoot->myParent->right = subTreeRoot->right;           
}
subTreeRoot->right->left = subTreeRoot;
subTreeRoot->right = NULL;  
subTreeRoot->height = 1;   
return;
```

This actually works.
It even works if a is not the root.

The test case that is failing is
something like
d c b a e

In this case I do the rotate and then come along and stick something else in.

I was going to go back and look at

http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~sgomori/570/avlrotations.html

But I wanted to make sure first I wasn't just barely off or else way to far off.

Comment: AVLs are a pain I know. To be honest I was attempting to help by looking at my AVL implementation for college that's 5 years old. I just realized I had been staring at my code for 10 min and can't remember how it works. Haha. Any luck since your post?

Comment: Yes, thanks for answering. 

I guess I need to post what I did as an answer.